# how do employers see freelancers?

Tags: interviewing, work-experience, freelancing

As I worked in Indian IT industry, recruiters sees freelancers as the one who are incompetent or who did not get work in any company.There is a stigma attached to it.As I am currently working as a freelancers.Does it happen here too(Canada)?

How do companies prioritize candidates based on full-time vs freelancing experience?

Comment: I made some edits to improve formatting. It is still not clear what you are asking, it sounds like you want a senior level position in terms of pay but aren't qualified and are asking how to get a job paying comparably anyways?

Comment: `I believe that I can earn more in a full-time job as compared to working as a freelancer.` Belief isn't a good foundation. What is the actual market for your skills? At least around here, freelancers make ~50% more than salaried employees.

Comment: In my present situation, I make 25$ per hour and work is not regular.And full-time job pay goes from 60K to75K.

Comment: "How should I deal with this situation where I want a high paying job, but at the same time I want a entry level or intermediate job?" You want a high-paying entry level job? Sorry, that is about as easy as getting a low-cost personal helicopter. No can do.

Comment: If you're not finding more work nor willing to ask for more money, you may want to stop being a freelancer.

Comment: @C4CodeE4Exe as a contractor you need to charge a lot more 75% -100%  more per hour as a freelance to cover you holidays and down times

Answer (score 4):

Freelancing is essentially contracting, so I don't think it mars you. If you don't feel you are making enough money freelancing, talk to a contracting company. The pay is generally quite good, but you are not guaranteed to have a job from month to month. Additionally, most of the companies I've dealt with will have very seasoned people on staff/contract that can be used to help train/teach a technology/language. You'll get a wide exposure to technology and good pay.

My expectation is that if someone lists 4 years of experience, they know how to write some code, even if it's been a few years. Stop doing that. Instead of time writing with a language, write your resume to state what you feel your level is in a given tech; be honest. Why would you market yourself as a Java developer when you admit you don't remember any of it?

There is nothing wrong with full time employment either. But, two years of solid experience might push you into the lower end of an intermediate developer unless you are a rock star. You are not going to get out of college making "high pay" unless your skills merit it.

As far as convincing someone you can do a job, that is all you. You have to be able to

1. Sell yourself. Make a good impression, be personable, and be genuine.
2. Talk well about whatever the technologies are for the job. Don't go after jobs you can't handle. It'll be disappointing, embarrassing, and a waste of time.
3. Explain how you have succeeded in similar situations in the past

Comment: +1 for I don't think it mars you and Don't go after jobs you can't handle.By "you don't remember any of it", I mean recently I got a coding challenge from a company and as per them, it needs 8-10 hours of work.I actually took 25 hours to complete the challenge in Java.

Comment: @C4CodeE4Exe If it only takes you twice as long as someone thinks it should have taken, then I'd say that is far better than "not remembering any of it." With any skill you get rusty after a period of disuse. If you want to improve the skill you have to maybe invest some time in Code-fu or something to improve your skills.